# Consolidate multiple .txt files into a single data frame

Tags: r

I am new to this and this is my first post, so forgive me if something is unclear!

I am currently working with Raven Pro 1.5 and R-Studio (warbleR-Package) and want to consolidate my data from Raven into a single data csv-file, including:

```
sound.files,"selection","start","end","sel.comment","rec.comment"
```

Raven Pro gives me approx. 2000 .txt files, containing the following columns:

```
"Selection  View    Channel Begin Time (s)  End Time (s)    Low Freq (Hz)   High Freq (Hz)  Occupancy".
```

The problem is that it doesn't include the file-name in the .txt file.

Since I have actually no idea on how to start I'd appreciate every kind of help!

In the end I need a .csv-file like this:

```
sound.files,"selec","start","end","sel.comment","rec.comment"
20190606_210800.WAV,1,6.12861572496447,6.81117905911277,"",""
20190606_210900.WAV,2,8.12133424234324,9.12319435,"",""
20190607_201900.WAV,1,2.23842309523095,2.89123114,"",""
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Look at the `list.files()` function. You can use it with a file name pattern and get the list of files. Then, use `lapply` (for example) to read these files and maybe `Reduce` or `merge` to join them. Hard to tell you more without having a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you!

But I've already found a solution. I forgot that there's actually a page with exactly that code!

So in case anybody looks for exactly that:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rraven/vignettes/Rraven.html

There ya go!

Comment: Please consider writing an answer to your question so we all can learn even if your link goes down tomorrow.